# When I add a Three-digit number to my array and show it the array thinks i entered three values

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add some numeric values to an array and then show the array items (in Javascript) .

When I enter 222 in my textbox and click add and then show . I wanna show each array item in a row .

But the tables show 222 Like :

[ScreenShot](http://imageupload.co.uk/files/8v14wku9eboy6o3m17pv.png)

What is the problem . Here is mj Javascript code :

```
function display()
{
    for(var i in array)
    {   
        document.getElementById("show").innerHTML+=parseFloat(array[i])+"<br>";
    }
    alert(array.length);
}
```

**the alert shows : 3**

insert code :

```
function add()
{
    var nevalue=document.getElementById("adad").value;
    array+=parseFloat(nevalue);

    document.getElementById("adad").value="";
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML="";
}
```

Comment: And what's in the `array` variable? Can you show enough JavaScript and HTML to reproduce your problem? Without it we can only guess, and that's not a great way to help.

Comment: You need to show us how you put the value into your array

Comment: `for-in` in JavaScript is intended for iterating object properties, _not_ for array elements where it can produce unexpected results.  The proper way to loop an array is `for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++)` with an incremental loop.

Comment: you are probably looping over the string itself and not an array object

Comment: yep, `array+=` doesn't work. If you initialized your array properly `var array = []` then the correct way to append something to it, is the `push` function. `array.push(parseFloat(nevalue))`

Comment: @ Michael Berkowski            Oh .... Your code has the same problem :(

Comment: @basilikum thanks ... The cause of i used that code was my teacher told me not to use push() method , Because he hasn't taught it yet .

Comment: Never listen to your teachers.

Comment: @PatrickEvans     Bad Boy ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not accessing the array the correct way.

```
var arr = new Array(); 
// or 
var arr = [];
function add()
{
 var nevalue=document.getElementById("adad").value;
 arr.push(parseFloat(nevalue));

 document.getElementById("adad").value="";
 document.getElementById("show").innerHTML="";

}

function display()
{
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
  {   
     document.getElementById("show").innerHTML+=parseFloat(arr[i])+"<br>";
  }
  alert(arr.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add elements into an array with `+=`.  The result of trying to do that is that the variable which previously held your array now contains a string.  You are then looping over the characters in the string when you think you're looping over an array.

http://jsfiddle.net/mtg2J/

```
var arr = [];

arr+="abc";

alert(typeof arr);  // alerts 'string'
```

This is equivalent to:

```
var arr = [];

arr = arr + "abc";  // the + is string concatenation, making the result a string.
```